# Сумма двух float-чисел вычисляется не верно

Tags: java, float

Объясните, пожалуйста, что со мной не так, или почему результат вычислений столь странный? Здесь же даже нечего отрубать(округлять), если бы мы допустим хотели показать `(1/3)`.
На сколько понимаю: `11.4+5.7 = 11.0+5.0 + 1.1 = 17.1`
Так в школе ещё объясняли...

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.println(11.4f+5.7f);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
17.099998
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подобные ошибки связанны с внутренним двоичным (binary) представлением
>   чисел. Подобно тому, как в десятичной системе нельзя точно представить
>   результат деления 1/3, так и в двоичной системе невозможно точно
>   представить 1/10.

Подробнее [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/)

В двух словах, числа с плавающей точкой не подходят для арифметических вычислений. Если вы хотите иметь возможность выполнять арифметические действия над дробными числами, используйте класс `BigDecimal`

Comment: Аж стыдно, что я задал этот вопрос хаха. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Direct, все приходит с опытом. Возможно этот вопрос скоро удалят. diraria нашел дубликат этого вопроса